# mysql insert with value equal to primary key + 1

Tags: mysql, insert

I have an auto increment column ID, and **for some situation** I wanted the other column to be equal to the primary key + 1 value

```
ID | other
1  | 2
2  | 3
3  | 4
4  | 123 (some situation, it is not always plus 1)
```

How can I achieve this?

Here's what I have tried

```
INSERT INTO table (`ID`,`other`) VALUES ('',(SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM table))
```

But that returns an error

```
You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: First rule of asking here - show us your code and what have you tried to achieve this yourself.

Comment: you can use trigger on this table. update "other" column after inserting data update tablename set other = ID + 1

Comment: If it's always going to be ID + 1, why does it need to be a separate column? You can use it in queries by referring to "id + 1" for example SELECT id + 1 AS other from <tablename>;

Comment: @Hirengardhariya adding 1 to the 'other' column must not always happening. I only do that for some condition.

Comment: @VyassaBaratham it's NOT always going to be ID + 1

Comment: @ivory-santos Please clerify in which situation you have to use (ID +1)

Answer (score 0):

Try Below query:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table ADD
Column  AS ([ID]+1)
GO
```

It will definitely work

Comment: it's NOT always going to be ID + 1

Comment: Whatever it should be.. we just need to put calculation. For example
Column  AS `([ID]+1) * 10`

Or you can use Case as well

`ALTER TABLE dbo.tblNNN ADD
    Other3  AS case ID when 1 then [ID] + 1 else [ID] +2  end
GO`

Comment: @NitinChaurasia You're talking SQL server, the question is about MySQL that does not (afaik still) have computed column support.

Answer (score 0):

Using a normal `AUTO_INCREMENT` column as id, I cannot think of a way to do this in MySQL. Triggers, which otherwise would have been an option, don't work well with `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns.

The only way I see is to do two commands for an `INSERT`;

```
INSERT INTO bop (value) VALUES ('These values should be 1 and 2');
UPDATE bop SET other = id+1 WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d34e3/1).

The closest I'm getting to what you're looking for is to generate sequences separately from `AUTO_INCREMENT` using a function, and use that instead to generate the table id;

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TABLE bop (
  id INT UNIQUE,
  other INT,
  value VARCHAR(64)
)//

CREATE TABLE bop_seq ( seq INT ) //    -- Sequence table
INSERT INTO bop_seq VALUES (1)   //    -- Start value

CREATE FUNCTION bop_nextval() RETURNS int
BEGIN
  SET @tmp = (SELECT seq FROM bop_seq FOR UPDATE);
  UPDATE bop_seq SET seq = seq + 1;
  RETURN @tmp;
END//

CREATE TRIGGER bop_auto BEFORE INSERT ON bop
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.id = bop_nextval(), NEW.other=NEW.id + 1;
//
```

That'd let you do inserts and have it autonumber like you want. The `FOR UPDATE` should keep the sequence transaction safe, but I've not load tested so you may want to do that.

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63ade/1).

Comment: yup, I already thought of it. But I want to find a query which don't need to do a command twice. Thanks by the way!

Comment: @ivory-santos I can't think of another way to do it, but you should be able to send both queries in the same batch so that they don't cause two separate roundtrips to the database.

Comment: @ivory-santos Updated with a trigger solution that may do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by updating 2 times the DB..

I wanted to do +1 from 19 till ..

```
UPDATE `table` SET `id`=`id`+101 WHERE id <= 19 
UPDATE `table` SET `id`=`id`-100 WHERE id <= 119 AND id >= 101
```